# Hibernate EntityManager#getResultList is hanging without any error

Tags: java, hibernate, locking

It was working fine till this day, no changes in code were made, so I am wondering how it could happen:

I have a following snippet in my project

```
Query query = manager.createNativeQuery(nativeQuery, Entity.class);
entities = query.getResultList();
```

The application is hanging on getResultList method.
I guess it is a kind of lock in database, but why it was working all the time before today?
And how should I fix it?

P.S. this lines of code are inside a method marked as `@Transactional("transactionManager")`